# I keep getting ERROR 404 in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just got started with CodeIgniter and I'm working on this example https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

This is my URL:

localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/CodeIgniter
-3.1.5/index.php/application/controllers/pages/view/about

I don't think there is anything wrong with it, but I keep getting error 404 when I try to access it.

Comment: Have you named your pages controller where the file name and class has first letter upper case only. `Pages.php` and `class Pages extends CI_Controller {}`  It also could be you need a htaccess in main directory.

Comment: Error 404 is Page Not Found error.  Your path is wrong.  Does localhost send you somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have named the controller Pages.php and I have a htaccess file

Comment: @Eric It is supposed to take me to the about page

Comment: Your application folder at the root of your web server is called CodeIgniter-3.1.5?

Comment: @Eric Yes, it's called CodeIgniter-3.1.5

Comment: Before I go into any details... does your url localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/CodeIgniter -3.1.5/index.php/ work?

Comment: your url look not right

Comment: you can used page route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is wrong.

if you have proper .htaccess, your url should look like :

```
localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/Pages/view/about
```

and without proper .htaccess file :

```
localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/CodeIgniter-3.1.5/index.php/Pages/view/about
```

and this is a proper .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```